# Rstudio: object not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I've clearly defined what standard_deviation is but my code still cannot find it. I tried using many different names instead of "standard_deviation" but none of them work

Comment: The code in your image does not assign the output from `summarise` to a variable, which  is why the column name is not found.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code but I still got the error message "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'standard_deviation' not found". In general, I'm having problems retrieving variables in my summarise functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not assign the output from `summarise` to a variable that `ggplot` can use.

You might try piping the output from `summarise` directly to `ggplot` like this:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(LastMaths) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(atsqTotal), 
            standard_deviation = sd(atsqTotal)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(LastMaths, Mean)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - standard_deviation, 
                    ymax = Mean + standard_deviation), width = 0.1)
```

Comment: I don't understand how ggplot was able to use the "mean" output in my summarise function as I only got an error message for the "standard_deviation" output.

Comment: It wasn't using the `mean` output. It assumed that `mean` was the name of the function, not a variable - and that function does exist. That's why it's best not to use existing function names for variable names.